# Seeking Obituaries for Midland, Texas from 1970s and before?

Tags: united-states, texas, 1970s, obituary

I am looking for a directory online in which I could view old obituaries from Midland, Texas, USA.

There are plenty of places to view recent ones, but where can I view older ones.

I am particularly looking for ones from around the 1970s.

Comment: This earlier Q&A concerns Texas obituaries from the 1930s.  Nevertheless, it may be useful to you. http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/9476.

Comment: I have downvoted the question because it is unclear what you're asking, especially in light of your comments on the answers.  Do you want a newspaper directory, an obituary index, or sites where you can view the actual newspapers online?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primary newspaper for Midland, Texas, is the [Midland Reporter-Telegram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midland_Reporter-Telegram) (found by searching for "newspaper" on the "[Midland, Texas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midland,_Texas)" wikipedia page).

Google "midland reporter telegram archives" and one of the top hits is "[Midland Reporter Telegram Newspaper Archives (1941-1977)](https://newspaperarchive.com/us/texas/midland/midland-reporter-telegram/)

Comment: Yes, the Midland Reporter-Telegram is the newspaper here in Midland. (I live in Midland, so I know.) I will try searching around in here.

Comment: @ezra Given you live in Midland, I would suggest you don't restrict your question to only online resources. It seems like you would have fairly easy access to local libraries and archives, which may be much more fruitful to search. I'm sure there are many obituaries for the area that are not digitised yet.

Comment: @HarryVervet - That would be a good idea, but that's not what I asked. I know I can go to some local place and access some stuff, you could just say I am a lazy/busy genealogist novice. : ) I plan on going somewhere though to further my search.

Answer (score -1):

At the [Midland County, Texas Genealogy page of FamilySearch.org](https://familysearch.org/wiki/en/Midland_County,_Texas_Genealogy#Obituaries) I found a list of sites that it may be worth you investigating:

> - Obituaries of Midland County ~partial listing of obituaries submitted by researchers
> - Obituary Resources ~ Links to research and locate obituaries ~  Hidden Ancestors
> - USGenWeb Archives Obituary Project  ~  Texas
> - Afrigeneas ~ African American death notices, obituaries and funeral programs compiled by users from current newspapers and historical
>     sources
> - Obituary Depot  ~  Texas Newspaper Citations
> - Obituary Project ~ Hidden Ancestors
> - Obituary Daily Times  ~  Citations to over 15,000,000 obituaries including interactive search function

Comment: -1 because none of those sites contain obituaries from the 1970s or earlier, and few of them contain any at all for Midland

Comment: @HarryVervet that's fair - I ran out of time to volunteer to check each link and just wanted to make sure that the asker had visited FamilySearch.org to see what it might offer. If better answers come in I will delete this one.